# Regex to combine 2 lines of text into 1

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following script with me

```
141
00:07:13,000 --> 00:07:16,680
So when you access a
web page such as google.com,

142
00:07:16,751 --> 00:07:20,824
really what you're
accessing is google.com/

143
00:07:20,824 --> 00:07:22,872
and the forward slash there just means

144
00:07:22,780 --> 00:07:26,180
this is the homepage of the site.
```

I want to merge the two lines of the text into 1 single line. For example:

```
really what you're
accessing is google.com/
```

will look like `really what you're accessing is google.com/`

I am trying to achieve this through notepad. This is the regex I have created: `\D\r\n\D` and I replace this with space.

On running this, the output is `really what you'r ccessing is google.com`

The last character of the first line and first character of second line is missing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try this: In `Find What` use `(\D)\r\n(\D)`. In `Replace with` use `$1 $2`. See if that helps.

Comment: This works! Thanks
Can I also add something to get a blank line after this?

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, which you can mark as accepted to put closure to your question

Comment: Yes, you can add a blank line by typing in `Find what` this `^(\d{3})` and in `Replace with` this `\r\n$1` **after** you have run the first set of replacement. It may not be perfect, but you can tweak that solution to your liking.

Comment: Your question has 2 answers. Could you please accept one of the answers to give closure to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\D` which could also match a newline, you can match any char except a digit or a newline using `[^\d\r\n]` keeping the newlines after it.

Then use `\R` to match a newline sequence while asserting that on the left and right `[^\d\r\n]` is present.

In the replacement use a space.

```
(?<=[^\d\r\n])\R(?=[^\d\r\n])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KMi6Lo/1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, you can do this:

[image: Picture]

The first item is `(\D)` is called `$1` and the second `(\D)` is called `$2`. The way you were using regex, both the `\D` were being deleted. In my regex replacement, I am putting those last characters and adding a space between them.